# Difference between ngInclude and ngBindHtml

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-bind-html, angularjs-ng-include

What is the difference between [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) and [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) in angular?? 
imagine a case when based on some parameters the `html` will change rather to be for example an image tag or span tag; so There should be a mechanism to add that dynamic `html`
for example

```
<!--dynamichtml : <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>-->
<a ng-include="'dynamichtml.html'"></a> 
<a ng-bind-html="dynamichtml"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

[`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) is described as follows:

> Evaluates the expression and inserts the resulting HTML into the element[...]

[`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), on the other hand

> Fetches, compiles and includes an external HTML fragment.

The value in `ng-bind-html` should evaluate to valid HTML. The value in ng-include should evaluate to a valid URL.

Comment: could you please show the final html result of the example in question?? because unfortunately it wont show up in `inspect element`

Comment: why not change the value of `dynamichtml` to something like `'hello world'`?

Comment: because `'hello world'` does not include any `html tag` itself

Answer (score 1):

> ng-bind-html

`ng-bind-html` is used when one has a model that contains HTML in the *string* format. On binding the model with that of the DOM, this gets updated in the element, as its child.

> ng-include

This adds an external `html` file in the DOM. Here, it doesn't gets bind, but only gets attached.

It depends upon the application and the model states, based on which one can decide with which `directive` to make use of.

Here, you can read more about [ng-bind-html](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) and [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Comment: could you please show the final html result of the example in question?? because unfortunately it wont show up in `inspect element`

Comment: Please find the plukr URL -> https://plnkr.co/edit/Rkth9cIRsfiSh7rxvbmE?p=preview

Comment: Is the html like this at the end? <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div><div><h3>This is the included HTML file.</h3></div></div>
    <div><p>This is the binded HTML coming from controller.</p></div>